# Función llamada veces que muestre por consola 5 veces el número 5

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles

Es un ejercicio sencillo y no entiendo porque no queda, por favor ayuda! no encuentro el error

```
function veces() {
  for (let n = 0; n < 5; n++) {
    console.log(n);
  }
}
```

Comment: Debes imprimir el valor 5 en la consola, no el valor de n.

Comment: ya lo intente imprimir el valor "5" pero tampoco se puede

Comment: Lo que comenta @JhonRayo99 debería funcionar, `console.log(5)`, esto va a mostrar en consola un circulo azulado con el numero 5 dentro y a continuación un número 5.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo observado no veo ninguna razón para que no funcione.

Esta es una ejecución usando el inspector de Google Chrome, aquí el loop sin la función:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí la función y su llamado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber o que nos envies una captura de donde estas haciendo la ejecución o el ambiente de desarrollo. Nuevamente te digo, es muy raro.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Mariam quiero explicarte algo sencillo.

La función de la variable n es definir cuantas veces se repetirá el bucle o ciclo.

Si quieres una función que imprima el numero 5, 5 veces. Debes hacer un ciclo que se repita 5 veces, donde i = 0; i <5; i++ y luego imprimir el pantalla con un console.log() o un document.write() el valor que quieres mostrar.